# Document Storage and Approval

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list

I am trying to design a solution for one of our business unit to store process design documents (Visio docs). I am storing it in a list as attachment with some of the attributes stored in list columns. Anyone should be able to upload or modify a document but it needs to go through an approval process. Need to retain all the versions of a document but only last approved should be available to users.

Need help with what will be the best approach?

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an Approval Workflow.  Create one for each type of approval (Manager, Peer, Technical Author) etc, and then, when a document is updated, you can set the workflow off automatically or manually.  The Approval Workflow will email each of the defined approvers and ask them to review and then approve/reject the document.
You can stop the document being published until its been approved.You can also record who approved it, and when.

Comment: Marc thanks for reply I understand that but issue to handle is when a user modify an existing document?

Comment: You can use the Workflow Settings option.  Create your approval workflow, with all the necessary timings and email addresses, and at the end, there is an option 'Changing an item will start this workflow'.  Just check it.